# How can I use Performance Counter in w2k8

Tags: .net, security, performancecounter, perfmon, rights-management

Problem:

I can add+use performance counters in w2k8 with normal user privileges.

If I try to create or access a Process performance counter, i get a message that the counter does not exist.

Same thing can be tried out in a powershell, a message appears that the counter does not exist.

If I do the same thing as Administrator account (not any administrator account, THE Administrator acoount), I can access the counter without any problem.

Other counters (like processor) work fine with normal user oder admin user accounts.

So what is needed to access process counters from a (let's say .net) programm without the need of the Administrator account?

tia

p.s.  no, I won't sign in. Don't like OpenID

Comment: Can you post your code. I use alot of perf counters just fine on 2k8. Can you repro your problem on another OS like 2k3

Answer (score 0):

You can access it without the administrator account, but whatever account you do use has to be an administrator, and have administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

The other account where only this type of counter doesn't work has local administrator privileges. Therefore that is not the answer. I forgot to mention: UAC is turned on on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using WMI to create & read the performance counters or you'd be getting a UnauthorizedAccessException. Unless we know what language and true method you're using to do this, we're not going to be much help.

There are ways of working with the Longhorn kernel that don't rely on making a change to the local system to make it work. Making sure you have your application signed and using the right permissions on the project can help.